# Unable to configure less-loader with Electron React Boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron, less, electron-react-boilerplate

I am using **Ant Design** with **Electron React Boilerplate** and need to load less file as global styles to customize its theme colors as mentioned [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#Customize-in-webpack). I have configured less-loader in **`webpack.config.renderer.dev.babel.js`** and **`webpack.config.renderer.prod.babel.js`** as

```
{
    test: /\.less$/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'style-loader',
    }, {
      loader: 'css-loader',
    }, {
      loader: 'less-loader',
      options: {
        lessOptions: {
          modifyVars: {
            'primary-color': '#e6315a',
            'link-color': '#e6315a',
            'border-radius-base': '2px',
          },
          javascriptEnabled: true,
        },
      },
    }],
  },
```

and this is my **less file** **`app.global.less`**

```
@import '~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
@import '~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
@import '~antd/dist/antd.less';
```

when I try to run in **development** using **`yarn dev`**, it runs good with customize theme colors but when I try to run in **production** using **`yarn start`**, it shows blank screen with this error
[image: Unable to load preload script: D:\easysale-electron\app\dist\renderer.prod.js]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just replace `loader: 'style-loader',` with `loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader` in the webpack.config.renderer.prod.babel.js

the global.less
[global less](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH25e.png)

other .less files
[less file not the global](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mudV8.png)

Hope this can help you